# Facebook Graph API how to upload image in node.js?

Tags: node.js, image, facebook-graph-api, upload

I am trying to follow this guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/resumable-upload-api

After researching how to attach multipart/form-data, as is suggested in the guide I came up with this code:

```
    const FB = require("fb")
    const fs = Npm.require("fs")

    FB.setAccessToken(accesstoken)

    const post = async () => {
        let res = await FB.api("app/uploads", "post", {
            file_type: "image/jpeg",
            file_length: file_length,
        })
        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? "error occurred" : res.error)
            return
        }
        const http = require("http")
        const FormData = require("form-data")

        const form = new FormData()
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(imagepath)
        form.append("file", readStream)

        const req = http.request({
            host: "graph.facebook.com",
            headers: {
                Authorization:
                    "OAuth accesstoken",
                file_offset: 0,
                Connection: "close",
                ...form.getHeaders(),
            },
            method: "POST",
            path: "/" + res.id,
        })

        form.pipe(req, { end: true })

        req.on("response", function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        })

        return res
    }
```

I want to be getting the uploaded file handle, but all Im getting in the response is a huge object, that starts like this (with statusCode 200):

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null, ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Probably the way I am attaching the file. The guide doesnt state which name to give it, so I just named it "file".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, although its probably not optimal:

```
    const FB = require("fb")
    const fs = Npm.require("fs")

    FB.setAccessToken(accessToken)

    let post = async () => {
        let res = await FB.api("app/uploads", "post", {
            file_type: "image/jpeg",
            file_length: file_length,
        })
        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? "error occurred" : res.error)
            return
        }
        
        const request = require("request")

        request.post({
            url: "http://graph.facebook.com/" + res.id,
            formData: {
                source: {
                    value: fs.createReadStream(imagePath),
                    options: {
                        filename: filename,
                        contentType: "image/jpeg",
                    },
                },
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization:
                    "OAuth AccessToken",
                file_offset: 0,
                Connection: "close",
                'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        },
        function (err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error!")
            } else {
                console.log("URL: " + body)
            }
        })

        return res
    }

    return post()
```